# Pandas: Dictionary column into key and value column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
                   {"colA": [1],
                    "colB": [[{"code1": 17}, {"code2": 18}, {"code3": 19}]]
                   }
                  )
>> df

    colA    colB
0   1       [{'code1': 17}, {'code2': 18}, {'code3': 19}]
```

Using `explode` I converted list into rows

```
>> df.explode('colB')

    colA    colB
0   1       {'code1': 17}
0   1       {'code2': 18}
0   1       {'code3': 19}
```

I want to convert the colB into key and value column

```
colA  colB_key  colB_value
 1      code1      17
 1      code2      18   
 1      code3      19
```

I am unable to proceed ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract columns, create list of tuples and pass to `DataFrame` constructor, for correct join by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) create default index by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) after `explode`:

```
df = df.explode('colB').reset_index(drop=True)

df1 = pd.DataFrame([list(x.items())[0] for x in df.pop('colB')], 
                   columns=['colB_key','colB_value'])
df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
   colA colB_key  colB_value
0     1    code1          17
1     1    code2          18
2     1    code3          19
```

Another idea:

```
L = [(a, *list(x.items())[0]) for a, b in zip(df['colA'], df['colB']) for x in b]

df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['colA','colB_key','colB_value'])
print (df)
   colA colB_key  colB_value
0     1    code1          17
1     1    code2          18
2     1    code3          19
```